# configure localhost to send email using servlet

Tags: java, jsp, email, servlets, ejb

I have written a simple program to send email. The servlet program and JSP code is below. I get the following error message in jsp page. I am using glassfish server. I have added following jar file to my class path.

1. lib/mail.jar
2. lib/dsn.jar
3. lib/imap.jar
4. lib/mailapi.jar
5. lib/pop3.jar
6. lib/smtp.jar
7. lib/activation.jar

I am working in windows 7 platform and using netbeans IDE.

sender email id=someone@mohp.gov.np
reciever email id=someone@gmail.com

### Error Message

```
Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1
```

### SERVLET CODE in doPOST() method

```
String err="";

        //reciever email ID
//reciever email id=someone@gmail.com
        String to=request.getParameter("reciever");

        //sender emai ID
//sender email id=someone@mohp.gov.np

        String from=request.getParameter("sender");

        //Assuming sending email from localhost
        String host="localhost";

        //Subject of the email;
        String sub=request.getParameter("subject");

        //message of the email
        String msg=request.getParameter("message");

        //get system properties
        Properties properties=System.getProperties();

        //Setup mail server
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

        //get the default Session object
        Session session=Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

        try{
            //Create a default MimeMessage object.
            MimeMessage message=new MimeMessage(session);

            //set FROM: header field of the header.
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

            //set TO: header field of the header.
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));

            //set subject:
            message.setSubject(sub);

            //set message:
            message.setText(msg);

            //Send message

            Transport.send(message);


        }catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
            err=mex.getMessage();
        }

        request.setAttribute("err", err);
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/newjsp.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
```

### JSP CODE(index.jsp)

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/email.css" type="text/css">
        <title>E-Mail</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="EMail" method="post" name="myform">
            <table border="1" width="100%" height="600px" cell-padding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td><table>
                    <tr height="30px">
                        <td width="5%" align="left">From :</td>
                        <td width="80%"><input type="text" name="sender" value="" size="80" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr height="30px">
                        <td width="5%">To :</td>
                        <td width="80%"><input type="text" name="reciever" value="" size="80" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr height="30px">
                        <td width="5%">Subject :</td>
                        <td width="80%"><input type="text" name="subject" size="100" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr height="30px">
                        <td width="5%">Message :<br></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <table>
                        <tr height="30px">
                            <td width="5%"><textarea name="message" rows="20" cols="85"></textarea>"</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="Submit" value="Send"</td>
                    </tr>
                </table></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

### JSP CODE (newjsp.jsp)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        ${err}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are trying to you an smtp server on localhost.  Do you really have SMTP server locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must set your email authentication credentials to session object.use the below code to set authentication credentials

```
 Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    @Override
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("yourmail@gmail.com", "yourpassword");
                    }
                });
        mailSession.setDebug(true);
        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setContent(content, "text/html");

        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(emailid));

        transport.connect(SMTP_HOST_NAME, SMTP_HOST_PORT, "yourmail@gmail.com", "yourpassword");

        transport.sendMessage(message,
                message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));

        transport.close();
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you are not setting all the mandatory properties to send email and mail.smpts.host is the port number.please change localhost to 465 and please check the below properties are in your code

Properties props = new Properties();

```
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
props.put("mail.smtps.host", 465);
props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
        "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. @Selva Kumar, I added the above code and its working but its asking for some password. Here is the messsage i get now.

'failed to connect, no password specified?'

I have also added the following code to provide username and password but its still not working.

'properties.setProperty("mail.user", "me@domain");'
       ' properties.setProperty("mail.password", "myPassword");'

Comment: you have to give your email id and password in two lines.that are   return new PasswordAuthentication("yourmail@gmail.com", "yourpassword"); and   transport.connect(SMTP_HOST_NAME, SMTP_HOST_PORT, "yourmail@gmail.com", "yourpassword"); please give your user name and password in this two lines and don't set password   and email in properties object